# How to get all users that uploaded avatars or have gravatars?

Tags: buddypress, avatar, gravatar

Is there a way to get all users that: 1) uploaded an avatar or 2) have a Gravatar? I want to filter users that doesn't meet one of these conditions.

**UPDATE**

I forget to mention that this is for Buddypress. Anyway, I found an answer for the first condition, this is the `bp_get_user_has_avatar()` function that checks if a given user ID has an uploaded avatar.

Now I need only a Gravatar validation for the second condition.

Comment: How did you "upload an avatar"? Does BuddyPress come with that functionality?

Comment: @kaiser By default? I don't know, but in my environment this is already implemented (not by me :)).

Comment: Gravatars are not locally stored or tracked. You would have to make a network request for each user to check. Also if you make a lot of requests to Gravatar service quickly it would block you out, so this won't work reliably.

Comment: I read the BuddyPress docs and it seems that the user avatar is a setting there. Could we reduce this question to "Users that have a Gravatar?" If not, then we have a slight problem as BuddyPress isn't part of core and not handled here.

Comment: How about @shanebp sugestion, this also will make multiple requests to Gravatar, or that function works differently?

Comment: We don't know as the BP source is highly customized. Please mind the scope: We do not handle 3rd party plugin code here (see: [help/dont-ask]). You can try helping yourself (see [BuddyPress::bp_core_fetch_avatar()](https://github.com/buddypress/BuddyPress/blob/57309f85f0a7b65fa8d4d40021d8fa038b716ed5/src/bp-core/bp-core-avatars.php#L176) or ask at the BuddyPress support forums.

Comment: @kaiser Sorry, but the reduced question, without mentioning BuddyPress, will not be anymore my question. I do not want to offense someone from the BuddyPress support forums, but I like more this community, so I always will ask here first. Even if my question will be considered off-topic, I always will get an answer here. I understand the reason of your decision, so I accept it.

Comment: From the `bp_core_fetch_avatar()` description: ["When a local avatar is not found, Gravatar is queried."](https://github.com/buddypress/BuddyPress/blob/57309f85f0a7b65fa8d4d40021d8fa038b716ed5/src/bp-core/bp-core-avatars.php#L99 "When a local avatar is not found, Gravatar is queried."), so @Rarst are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function   `bp_get_user_has_avatar()`  calls `bp_core_fetch_avatar` with this argument `'no_grav' => true`  so you could write your own function to see if a user is not using the default avatar:

```
function lurie_avatar_check( $user_id ) {
    $retval = false;

    if ( bp_core_fetch_avatar( array( 'item_id' => $user_id, 'no_grav' => false, 'html' => false ) ) != bp_core_avatar_default( 'local' ) )
        $retval = true;

    return $retval;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar

run a user lookup and qualify via `get_avatar`